# AX 2012 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, axapta

For example, I created a table A at sql server without using AX, then I execute a stored procedure P which created at sql server as well. The value from stored procedure P has been inserted into the table A.

Now I need to retrieve the records from table A to table B which AX created. Is it possible to make it?

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve the records from table A to table B".
Insert in B from A or join A and B from somewhere?

Comment: And what has the stored procedure to do with it?

Comment: Ya, Insert data to B from A. The stored procedure is used for calculating discount item to customer.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to make an AX batch job to periodically shuffle the data from A to B.

If A is in an other database than AX (as it should be), then use ODBC to read the data.
Read here [how to Connect to an External Database from X++ Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677510.aspx).

You could either delete the record in A or [mark it as updated](http://atomicax.com/content/selecting-and-updating-records-external-database).